# How do I use VLC Command Line In Windows Batch Line Without Showing GUI?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, vlc-media-player

I want to use the following to convert some M4A files to MP3. It works fine, but it displays the VLC GUI for each file and shows 'quit' as a second file to be converted. Is there a 'silent' mode, where it does the conversion with not graphics interface? Or is there something wrong with my syntax?

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b *.m4a') do (
  CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%%f" --sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=128,vcodec=dummy}:std{access="file",mux=raw,dst="converted/%%"} vlc://quit
)
```

UPDATE: I edited per Answer #1

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b *.m4a') do (
  CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%%f" --intf dummy --sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=128,vcodec=dummy}:std{access="file",mux=raw,dst=converted/"%%f"} vlc://quit
  move "%%f" trash/"%%f"
)
```

What it does is open a DOS command window as each file is processed. What I want is a totally silent mode (if possible). I have another batch file which does something similar (rips CD files to MP3) and it seems to work like that:

```
FOR /R D:\ %%G IN (*.cda) DO (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" -I http cdda:///D:/ --cdda-track=!y! :sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=%e%,ab=320,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access="file",mux=raw,dst="%t%!PADDED!.%e%"} vlc://quit
)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10):

You can use this:

```
vlc -I dummy --dummy-quiet {path_to_file}
```

As per [@MC10's answer](https://superuser.com/a/947120), the `-intf dummy` or `-I dummy` (they do the same thing) hides the GUI but still opens a second command line window. Use the additional `--dummy-quiet` option to hide this window too.

So, for your scenario:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b *.m4a') do (
    CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%%f" --I dummy --dummy-quiet --sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=128,vcodec=dummy}:std{access="file",mux=raw,dst=converted/"%%f"} vlc://quit
    move "%%f" trash/"%%f"
)
```

Comment: this works but on Windows 10 at least you can't close the video. The close button doesn't do anything, I had to kill the process

Comment: Unfortunately, `"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy --dummy-quiet --version vlc://quit` still pops up a batch window, and it doesn't look like the VLC people think that's a problem: https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/6866

Comment: --dummy-quiet doesn't hide the cmd window for me on Windows10. But -I dummy do hide the GUI.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is the [`dummy` interface](https://wiki.videolan.org/Interfaces/). This will give you no GUI.

Example:

> `% vlc --intf dummy vcd://`

**Edit:** While the dummy interface will give you no GUI, it will open a console. This is not what the question asked for so I am updating the answer.

This may be [**Linux** only](https://www.maketecheasier.com/mastering-vlc-via-the-command-line-linux/), I'm not sure yet. You can replace `vlc` with `cvlc` to get no interface at all.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding that to my bat file and it didn't work as expected (I updated my question to show the results.) What went wrong?

Comment: Oh I see. Does replacing `vlc` with `cvlc` work? I'm not sure if that's just a [Linux thing](https://www.maketecheasier.com/mastering-vlc-via-the-command-line-linux/).

Comment: No cvlc in Windows version. The thing is: my other example (ripping CD) works -exactly- as I want. Can't understand the difference.

Answer (score -2):

You're missing to call VLC as a server. Not sure, but it seems "-I http" parameters are what you need. Hope this help.