# How to run VLC as command line command in windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, vlc-media-player

When I try to use VLC in command line in Windows, it opens up the VLC GUI. So is there a way I can use it as command line command instead?

Comment: To confirm are you looking for a headless (No GUI) approach to executing VLC?

Comment: @CraftyB Yes. No GUI.

Answer (score 4):

Below is how to run headless vlc...

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy --dummy-quiet "c:\test\test.mp3"
```

Just to clarify...

```
<path to vlc player> -I dummy --dummy-quiet <path to file>
```

Question had already existed, please see source below:

[How do I use VLC Command Line In Windows Batch Line Without Showing GUI?](https://superuser.com/questions/947116/how-do-i-use-vlc-command-line-in-windows-batch-line-without-showing-gui)

Thanks @retnikt

Comment: you should flag it as a duplicate instead of copying the solution from there like this

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise that clicking flag has multiple options, I will use this in future. Thanks!

Comment: While this works in cmd, in PowerShell it fails with `Unexpected token '-I' in expression or statement.`. But prepending it with `& ` seems to fix the issue