# VLC Command Line - Run stream and then quit

Tags: command-line, audio, batch-file, vlc-media-player, streaming

I'm making Windows batch files that I can run and listen to a stream in VLC but then press any key to exit and stop the stream. This seems to work but I can see the batch freezes after starting VLC. This makes sense because VLC is now running mid command but now I'm not sure if you can even stop VLC after it's started via command?

Other things would be nifty to add, such as current bit rate and stuff but I just don't know enough about VLC command etc.

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
ECHO CBC Radio 1 - Calgary, Alberta
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy --dummy-quiet "https://cbcradiolive.akamaized.net/hls/live/2041039/ES_R1MCG/master.m3u8"
ECHO Press any key to quit.
PAUSE
vlc "https://cbcradiolive.akamaized.net/hls/live/2041039/ES_R1MCG/master.m3u8" vlc://quit
```

I'm thinking that the vlc://quit is for use while the app is running and may be part of the first command in actuality. But, this isn't an ending mp3. It's an endless live stream...

I've found a great answer at [How to run VLC as command line command in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1368080/how-to-run-vlc-as-command-line-command-in-windows/1368081#1368081) which links to an original question that is also great. I wanted to comment but I can't with 0 reputation in the last like 6 years. More info I obtained from https://nevillepark.ca/2019/09/17/cbc-radio-stream-urls/

--== 240212 Follow Up ==--

Thanks to https://superuser.com/users/576138/narzard

I created two files.
**VLC CBC Radio 1 - Calgary Alberta 192 Player.bat**
&
**VLC RUN-STOP CBC Radio 1 - Calgary Alberta 192.bat**

I removed the C directory from the 'radio.bat' command so that it runs within the current directory. Added some wording so that the player explains what it is. I have also structured it so each quality and location will be it's own set of files. MODE was added to the RUN-STOP so that the cmd window sizes to be a nice tiny fit on screen. I think I can work with this. Of course, it's expected that VLC is installed in the directory in the commands.

[The final window size and look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwUJT.png)

**VLC CBC Radio 1 - Calgary Alberta 192 Player.bat** contains this;

```
title CBC Radio 1 - Calgary Alberta 192 Player
@ECHO OFF
cls
ECHO PLAYER ONLY
ECHO Use 'Start' file to stop and close player.
ECHO ===========================================
ECHO Feed: CBC Radio 1 - Calgary, Alberta
ECHO Quality: 192kbps
ECHO Link: 'https://cbcradiolive.akamaized.net/hls/live/2041039/ES_R1MCG/adaptive_192/chunklist_ao.m3u8'
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy --dummy-quiet "https://cbcradiolive.akamaized.net/hls/live/2041039/ES_R1MCG/adaptive_192/chunklist_ao.m3u8"
```

**VLC RUN-STOP CBC Radio 1 - Calgary Alberta 192.bat** contains this;

```
title RUN/STOP CBC Radio 1 - Calgary, Alberta 192
@ECHO OFF
MODE 45,2
start /MIN cmd.exe /k "VLC CBC Radio 1 - Calgary Alberta 192 Player"
cls
echo Press any key to stop playback and close.
pause
taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq vlc*"
taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq CBC Radio 1 - Calgary Alberta 192 Player"
exit
```

Comment: Hello, what's the exact goal here? When do you want to press the key? After reactivating the CLI window? Or without reactivating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make 2 batch files and the first one can start the radio stream and allow for exit handling.

**StartStream.bat**

```
start /MIN cmd.exe /k "C:\temp\radio.bat"
echo Press any key to close
pause
taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq radio*"
exit
```

**radio.bat**

```
title radio
ECHO CBC Radio 1 - Calgary, Alberta
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy --dummy-quiet "https://cbcradiolive.akamaized.net/hls/live/2041039/ES_R1MCG/master.m3u8"
```

You would only ever click on `StartStream.bat` and then it will launch a second cmd window in the background. The second batch will start the radio and also set the window title to "radio". Because of this, in the first bat we are able to use taskkill to stop the stream directly and then close itself with exit. The only thing you have to change is the filepath in line 1 of StartStream.bat to point to your second bat.

Comment: I changed it up a bit to fit my needs but with your help I got it where I want. It's a crude but simple method. And I like it!